# Android app crashes only if it is run on my Google Pixel 2

Tags: java, android, xml

So whenever I put an image into my XML code like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/app_logo" />
```

It crashes when I run it on my Google Pixel 2 (API 27). But if I run it on the emulator for the pixel 2 (API 28) it runs just fine.

This is my full XML file for my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.jthomann.adelphi.MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSignup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Don't have account? Sign Up"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As soon as I add the image code into the XML file it crashes and I am not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

Java code that just displays the layout:

```
package com.jthomann.adelphi;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the crashlog

Comment: logcat would probably be helpful here..